# Value of char cannot be used to initialize an entity of char *

Tags: c++

I create a thread and send a string as a parametr. And I need to randomly shuffle the string but I have a problem here `char *c = buffer[rand() % len + 1]`. I've got an error `a value of type "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"`. Why and how can I solve it?

```
DWORD WINAPI secondThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    char *buffer = (char*)lpParam;
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);

    char result[CHAR_MAX];
    char *c = buffer[rand() % len + 1];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < len) {
        strcat(result, c);
        i++;
    }

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you replace `char result[CHAR_MAX];` with `char* result = new char[len + 1];` unless you know you will never get a string with more than `CHAR_MAX` characters in it.

Comment: Your `char*` should really be `const char*`, too. You don't intend to write to either `buffer` or `c`, so you might as well document intent. And have the compiler help you find bugs early on. Plus, you are writing past the end of `result`, unless `len` is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must take an address to assign to char*:

```
char *c = &buffer[rand() % len + 1]
          ^~~~~
```

also you should zero initialize `result` because when you use `strcat` you will append to destination buffer, and uninitialized `result` might not start with '\0' character. This should suffice:

```
char result[CHAR_MAX];
result[0] = '\0';
```

... but I strongly recomend you to switch `char result[CHAR_MAX];` to `std::string result;` and `strcat(result, c);` to `result += c;`